# output $action in Merge statement in Sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, merge

what is the use of output $action in Merge statement in Sql server 2008?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: I think this is a little unfair. He probably searched for $action instead of the OUTPUT parameter. All the search engines I've used removes the $ sign as it's a reserved keyword, which doesn't help the person doing the search.

Comment: This should be reopened as a real question, and "read the documentation" is not a good answer.

Comment: This should be reopened because searching MSDN places this question and answer as the first result. Also, note the comment for the MSDN page on `MERGE`.

Comment: I've voted for reopening.  The question is quite clear and reasonably well-defined.

Answer (score 17):

The all-knowing MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

> $action
>
> > Is available only for the MERGE statement. Specifies a column of type nvarchar(10) in the OUTPUT clause in a MERGE statement that returns one of three values for each row: 'INSERT', 'UPDATE', or 'DELETE', according to the action that was performed on that row.